# How to check the working of my django code by deploying the code on my device's IP address

Tags: python, django, ip

$ python manage.py runserver `113.193.144.56:80`

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
December 27, 2014 - 13:12:42
Django version 1.7.1, using settings 'usertracking.settings'
Starting development server at <code>113.193.144.56:80</code>
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

Error: That IP address can't be assigned-to.
```

Comment: You can't do that in django

Answer (score 0):

The IP's you can run in Django are either localhost `(0.0.0.0 / 127.0.0.1)` or the IP assigned to your device in a local access network (which should be of the kind of `192.168.1.xx`), unless you open a port with the router which I don't think it is the case. The IP you are using is the IP of the router.